# Return Type of a Function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, return-type

I am trying to write an AI in unity for a simple 2D game I have made, I am trying to use the code from a simple genetic algorithm tutorial on unity but I don't what type of return unity wants me to use for the code below. It is hard for me to explain as I don't know the names of the return type when not specified but the code is below. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dictionary<float, float> genes;
    int dnaLength;

    public DNA()
    {
        genes = new Dictionary<float, float>();
        SetRandom();
    }

    public void SetRandom()
    {
        genes.Clear();
        genes.Add(-1f, Random.Range(-1, 1));
        genes.Add(0f, Random.Range(-1, 1));
        genes.Add(1f, Random.Range(-1, 1));
        dnaLength = genes.Count;
    }

    public void Combine(DNA d1, DNA d2)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<float, float> newGenes = new Dictionary<float, float>();

        foreach(KeyValuePair<float, float> g in genes)
        {
            if (i < dnaLength / 2)
            {
                newGenes.Add(g.Key, d1[g.Key]);
            }
            else
            {
                newGenes.Add(g.Key, d2[g.Key]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        genes = newGenes;
    }

    public float GetGene(float front)
    {
        return genes[front];
    }
}
```

I tried having the DNA return a dictionary with both the key and value as a float, but then I would not be able to set random values.

Comment: also it wouldn't let me have the unity2d tag so keep in mind its a 2d game if that makes a difference

Comment: I assume `public DNA()` is meant to be a constructor. If so it needs to match the name of the class. If not please explain how you expect to use that function. In general in a `MonoBehavior` you want to do whatever you would do in a constructor in the `Awake` or `Start` function.